# Getting 'NetworkServer' does not contain a definition for 'SpawnWithClientAuthority'

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I'm getting 'NetworkServer' does not contain a definition for 'SpawnWithClientAuthority' here's my script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using Mirror;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ShootHooks : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject bulletPrefab;
    private GameObject hook;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!_camera) _camera = Camera.main;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        this.CmdInstantiateHook();
        //hook.SetActive(false);
        //localPlayer = ClientScene.localPlayer.gameObject;
    }


    [Command]
    void CmdInstantiateHook()
    {
        hook = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        NetworkServer.SpawnWithClientAuthority(hook, connectionToClient);       

        NetworkIdentity hookID = hook.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>();
        this.ClientAttachHook(connectionToClient, hookID);

        localPlayer = ClientScene.localPlayer.gameObject;

    }

    [Command]
    void CmdSetActiveServerHook(NetworkIdentity objectID)
    {
        NetworkIdentity.spawned[objectID.netId].gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    [TargetRpc]
    public void ClientAttachHook(NetworkConnection target, NetworkIdentity objectID)
    {
        hook = NetworkIdentity.spawned[objectID.netId].gameObject;
        this.CmdSetActiveServerHook(objectID);
    }

}
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure it is referring to the correct type? Do you have any other class that is also called `NetworkServer`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Mirror has deprecated SpawnWithClientAuthority. (https://mirror-networking.gitbook.io/docs/general/deprecations)

Please use Spawn(GameObject obj, NetworkConnection ownerConnection) instead.

[Screenshot from Mirror Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKYFO.png)